# Will I be considered for internships if I am not a student enrolled in a university?

Tags: hiring-process, internship, applications, hiring

I am currently working on a bootcamp for people with a scientific background to boost my skills for a certain type of tech career. As such, I am not really considered a student as I am not enrolled in a university for undergraduate or graduate work. However, nearly every internship I've found lists under its "requirements" that applicants must be pursuing X degree.

I have tried to apply to some of these internships where I mention current coursework within my cover letter in an attempt to show that I am still a student, even if not in a university. But I am wondering if my lack of official enrollment in a university at neither undergraduate nor graduate level is pushing my applications into the bin without consideration. Unless these companies are genuinely just taking MONTHS to get back to me.

Am I wasting my time applying? Are there other approaches I am unaware of? Any advice would be appreciated.

P.S. The reason I am pursuing internships and not full-time positions is because I am required to complete my coursework in a specific time frame with full-time effort, so I can only really manage a part-time position.

Edit: I am asking this question with the hopes that an HR person would lend their perspective. My bootcamp does have career services and I am certainly reaching out, but my question is whether or not my resume would get thrown out automatically because of it. I don't want to waste my time applying to a bunch of internships for nothing.

Comment: are you looking for paid or unpaid internships? What country are you living in?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I'm in the US. And preferably paid since my hope would be to work for that internship rather than a shaky part-time job.

Comment: Also, what warrants the downvotes here?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is a career advisor within the educational institute itself. They may have contacts or specific advice to give. If they don't it's not much of a bootcamp. In any case, just like a university that should be your first avenue to check out.

Apart from that all you can do is keep applying. One mistake people seem to make (in my opinion) is being fussy with the job that pays the bills while studying. Sure it's great if it's relevant to your studies, but a lot of people just took any part time job to make ends meet. I did cleaning and manual labour at some points while studying.

Comment: I do currently have a retail PTJ to help pay the bills but I would understandably prefer to do something more relevant if possible.

Comment: As would we all, I've NEVER held any sort of job in the field I studied at University, life took over instead

Comment: I'm not in university. But also, is it wrong to look into the possibility just because others don't?

Comment: Nope, by all means continue to apply as I said in my answer. You don't try you don't win.